# UIPageViewController or UICollectionView

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uipageviewcontroller

I'm building an app where a user can scroll sideways through articles. These articles are full screen, start with text and end with a fullscreen image. The image and text are fetched from an API.

I've built two implementations of this: one with a `UIPageViewController` and one with a `UICollectionView`.

The `UIPageViewController` loads 20 articles, where every article is an `ArticleViewController` that contains two `UIScrollView`s, a `UIImageView` and a `UIWebView`. The `UICollectionView` has 20 cells, where every cell is built like the `ArticleViewController`.

Sidenote: When I run them in the iOS Simulator, the first implementation eats 100MB memory. This makes no sense to me, since the `ArticleViewController` sets `self.view` to `nil` when it disappears.

Which of these is best to use in my use case?

Comment: do your articles require communication in between them?

Comment: in that case you can use page view.

Comment: Ever figure out any more info?

Comment: Was wondering if you figured out more info as well...